# How to write latency based Route 53 alias recordset resource in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

According to this AWS document [this AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-resourcerecords), I can create latency based resource record aliased to an application load balancer, but I do not see an option for Routing Policy in the syntax where I can define latency.

Here are my example recordsets in Route 53 console from, two different regions for the same application. Since it is an aliased record, my understanding is that I do not need use a Health Check configuration. I can just enable **Evaluate target health** instead.

**For us-east-1:**

- **Record name:** mywebsite.example.com
- **Record type:** A
- **Alias:** Yes
- **Route traffic to:** Alias to Application and Classic Load Balancer

  US East (East Virginia) [us-east-1]

  dualstack.internal-mywebsite-alb-1234567890.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
- **Routing policy:** Latency
- **Region:** US East (East Virginia)
- **Health check:** optional (None)
- **Evaluate target health:** Yes
- **Record ID:** us-east-1-mywebsite-alb

**For us-west-2:**

- **Record name:** mywebsite.example.com
- **Record type:** A
- **Alias:** Yes
- **Route traffic to:** Alias to Application and Classic Load Balancer

  US West (Oregon) [us-west-2]

  dualstack.internal-mywebsite-alb-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com.
- **Routing policy:** Latency
- **Region:** US West (Oregon)
- **Health check:** optional (None)
- **Evaluate target health:** Yes
- **Record ID:** us-west-2-mywebsite-alb

How can I transform them into CloudFormation resource(s)? A complete snippet for the resource would be very helful.

**Update:**

I have tried the following but did not work:

```
Resources:
  TestDevALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Type: application
      Scheme: internal
      # LoadBalancerAttributes:
      Subnets:
        - subnet-1111abcd2222abcde
        - subnet-2222abcd3333abcde
      SecurityGroups:
        - sg-1111abcd2222abcde

AlbDnsRecordSet:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    HostedZoneId: ABCD1234EFGH5678IJKL
    Name: testdev.example.com
    Type: A
    AliasTarget:
      HostedZoneId: !GetAtt 'TestDevALB.CanonicalHostedZoneID'
      DNSName: !GetAtt 'TestDevALB.DNSName'
    Region: us-west-2
```

I get error: `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Invalid template property or properties [AlbDnsRecordSet]`

**Update-2:**
The above error was due to indent. I added the target health check as well. The following worked. Thanks @marcin.

```
Resources:
  TestDevALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Type: application
      Scheme: internal
      # LoadBalancerAttributes:
      Subnets:
        - subnet-1111abcd2222abcde
        - subnet-2222abcd3333abcde
      SecurityGroups:
        - sg-1111abcd2222abcde

  AlbDnsRecordSet:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: ABCD1234EFGH5678IJKL
      Name: testdev.example.com
      Type: A
      AliasTarget:
        HostedZoneId: !GetAtt 'TestDevALB.CanonicalHostedZoneID'
        DNSName: !GetAtt 'TestDevALB.DNSName'
        EvaluateTargetHealth: true
      Region: us-west-2
      SetIdentifier: TestDev-uswest2
```

Comment: Do you have any template that you wrote to show? Why it does not work?

Comment: Hi Marcine, I updated the question and added the snippet I tried. Can you please check?

Comment: I think I'm approaching towards the solution. The error I got was for the indent. It created the record now, but need healthcheck. I will give further update soon

Comment: Glad it worked out:-)